# JavaScript scope with JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, scope

This function is called when an element is clicked. It creates a string based on what element was clicked, and then looks up the value associated with that string in a JSON object. It then alerts that value. Here's how it looks:

```
function alertHelp(){
    var option = $(this).context.parentNode.textContent.substring(0, $(this).context.parentNode.textContent.length - 2);
    $.getJSON("Messages.json", function(json, option) {
        alert(json[option]);
    });
}
```

What I've found is that option is set correctly, but then when passed to the function with the alert is changed. If I `alert(option)` right before `alert(json[object]);`, I get an alert that simply says "success". Not sure what's up with that. `alert(json[option])` simply alerts "undefined".

Here's Messages.json:

```
{
    "Space Control": "Red = a square black controls. Green = a square white controls. Yellow = a square contested by both players",
    "Legal Moves": "Click on a piece and a blue dot will appear on all the squares that piece can move to",
    "PieceFlair": "When you move a piece, all the pieces that come under attack as a direct result of the piece you moved will pulse white",
    "Forks": "All the moves that would result in a simultaneous attack of two pieces are shown",
    "Pins": "Not yet implemented"
}
```

Comment: can you post the content of Messages.json? it'd be useful to see the structure of the JSON to understand what's going on.

Comment: No problem. Done and done.

Comment: The reason `alert(option);` shows "success" is because you've redefined it as the second parameter to the callback: `, function(json, option) {`. Either don't include it (because I don't think you need it), or change the parameter name

Comment: I tried changing the parameter name. That didn't seem to do anything. I also tried just passing in a string like so     function(json, "Space Control") {    and that seemed to break everything, with an "Unexpected String" error being thrown.

Comment: @CaptainStack You can't use a string as a parameter name. You don't need the second parameter for the callback, so just use `, function(json) {`. Then, `alert(option);` to make sure it's set properly. If it looks right but isn't working, try trimming it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "shadowed" your `var option` by the `function` argument `option`, try this instead:

```
var text = $(this).context.parentNode.textContent;
var option = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);

$.getJSON("Messages.json", function(json, status) {
    alert(status);  // success
    alert(json[option]);
});
```

Comment: This definitely worked. I'm not sure I fully understand the solution though. I actually didn't realize that the variables would exist inside the function (still don't always understand scope in JavaScript). What I don't understand though is why the second parameter is redefined.

Comment: well the functions are nested, you can always access outer vars from inner functions, but not inner vars from outer functions. (the function sourrounding the var is it's "scope", a function that uses a var from outside is a "closure" for that var.)